# Add jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to build a server control that has a radiobuttonlist with 2 items and a textbox.
THe radio buttons are YES en NO options.

When YES is selected I want the textbox to be visible and it must be required to fill in.
On NO, the textbox becomes invisible.

I manages to get the textbox to appear and disappear based on the option choice.
But how do I add validation to the textbox and remove it when not visible?

I have tried it with the ASP validators, but the jquery doesn't disable them when the textbox is not visible.

I tried something like this, but it is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() 
{
  $('#TravelOption2_rbList').change(function() 
    { 
      var index = $('#TravelOption2_rbList input[type=radio]:checked').val(); 
      if (index != '0') 
        { 
           $('#TravelOption2_lblName2').css({'visibility':'visible'}); 
           $('#TravelOption2_txtName1').css({'visibility':'visible'}); 
           $('#TravelOption2_lblName3').css({'visibility':'visible'}); 

           // create validator (not working)
           $('#TravelOption2_txtName1').rules('add', { 
             required: true, 
             minlength: 2, 
             messages: { required: 'Required input', minlength: 'Please enter the cost.' } 
           }); 
        } else {
           $('#TravelOption2_lblName2').css({'visibility':'hidden'}); 
           $('#TravelOption2_txtName1').css({'visibility':'hidden'}); 
           $('#TravelOption2_lblName3').css({'visibility':'hidden'}); 

           // remove the validator here
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

I have seen a lot of examples but they are not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be easier to simply check if the textbox has at least 2 characters in it when you submit it's contents? I'm assuming this is some sort of input form.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() {
    $('#submitButton').on('click', function(){
      if ($('#TravelOption2_txtName1').val().length > 1 ) {
        //Textbox has at least 2 characters in it
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This server control is part of a form, but not a form itself. There is no submit button in it.

Comment: have you tried using the 'remove' argument for jquery validator?

`$('#TravelOption2_txtName1').rules('remove');`

http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/

Comment: No, because I have not been able to add a working validation.

Comment: I would like the validation to be done when the user leaves the textbox.